# python3 openpyxl not writing to cell

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Hello I am having issues writing to an a file using the openpyxl module. I am trying for a simple test What am I doing wrong?

```
def readInWorkbook():
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'myTracker.xlsx')
wb['A1'] = 'HEY we made it'
wb.save('myTracker.xlsx')
print("After save")
```

the error that I get is
File "tracker.py", line 10, in readInWorkbook
    wb['A1'] = 'HEY we made it'
AttributeError: **setitem**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write to a work book, where as you need to write to a work sheet.

```
def readInWorkbook():
    wb = load_workbook(filename = 'myTracker.xlsx')
    #Get active work sheet  
    ws = wb.active
    ws['A1'] = 'HEY we made it'
    wb.save('myTracker.xlsx')
    print("After save")
```